# Migrating data from RDBMS to ElasticSearch using Apache NIfi

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-nifi

We are trying to migrate data from RDBMS to elastic search using Apache Nifi. We have created pipelines in Nifi and are able to transfer data but are facing some issues and wanted to check if someone already got over them.

Please provide inputs on the below items.

1.How to avoid auto-generating _id in elastic search. We want this to be set from a DB column. We tried providing the column name in the "Identifier Record Path" attribute in the PutElasticSearchHTTPRecord processor but were getting an error that the attribute name is not valid. Can you please let us know the acceptable format.

2. How to load nested objects into the index using NIfi? We are looking to maintain one to many relationships in the index using nested objects but were unable to find a configuration to do so. Do we have any processors to do this in Nifi? Please let us know.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: >>were getting an error that the attribute name is not valid .. Did you check the flowfiles in the queue to make sure that the attribute you are using exist?

Comment: Yes... The field name is present in the flow file... We were giving the column name directly... Do we have any format we need to adhere to while mentioning the name of the identifier record path?

Comment: The field name should be as an attribute. Flowfile attribute (different from flowfile content). And AFAIK you can just use the attribute name. I have used it before and it has worked for me

Comment: Can you please let me know how to add an attribute. I was trying to add the content name and that was probably why I was running into an issue. Should we create attributes for each and every field present in the flow file content?
Any documentation pointers for this will help.

Comment: See if this helps https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Using-PutElasticsearchHttpRecord-CSVReader-in-Apache-NiFi-1/ta-p/246884

Answer (score 0):

1. It needs to be [a RecordPath statement](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/record-path-guide.html) like `/myidfield`
2. You need to manually create [nested fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) in Elasticsearch. This is not a NiFi thing, but how Elasticsearch works. If you were to post a document with `cURL`, you would run into the same issues.